# Case Insensitive search on Moodle

Tags: mysql, moodle, case-insensitive

I'm having an issue with Moodle search. I've installed the Course Search plugin that searches the DB for queries related to the course you are in.

I have a Test site (staging) using exactly the same code, and a copy of the (live) DB.

When i first installed the plugin the searches were case sensitive, giving me different results when i searched for example Quiz, quiz, QUIZ.

By changing the collation of the Staging DB to utf8_general_ci, i've managed to resolve this issue now on my staging site when i search for: quiz, Quiz, or QUIZ i get the same results.

However when i did that to the live DB, changing the collation of the tables to utf8_general_ci, still doesn't work, i get different results if i search lower case or upper case.

Everything is the same, code is the same, DB has the same collation.

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging i've found out that the columns of the database had a different collation than utf8_general_ci, they were using utf8_bin, after running a script and updating all the tables and columns to utf8_general_ci, the search is not case insensitive.

SQL query used to do that in case someone needs:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_db_table_name` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```